# How can I get the same font in tics and label of pgfplot?

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I try to reach the same font on all possible places within the pgf plot. After many hours in this forum and trials of written solutions I have no idea.

Many thanks for the help in advance.

Regards,
Th.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
% change fonts to sans serif then `tikzpicture' environment is started
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{
    \begingroup
        \changeFonts
}
% end scope (for font change)
\AfterEndEnvironment{tikzpicture}{
    \endgroup
}
\usepackage{sansmath}
% create a command to switch fonts in `tikzpicture' environments to a
% sans serif font
\newcommand*\changeFonts{
   \sffamily\sansmath
}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

10 <> $\mathsf 10$!

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel={Abscissa, $x_\mathsf{10}$}, ylabel={Ordinate, $y$}]
\addplot {x^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{A figure with a \texttt{pgfplots} axis.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Try adding `tick label style = {/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true}` after `begin{axis}[`

Answer (score 1):

You can change all the ticks label font to sansserif with

```
\pgfplotsset{my style/.append style={xticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$},

 yticklabel={$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}}$} } }
```

And then adding `my style` to axis options:

`begin{axis}[my style, xlabel={Abscissa, $x_\mathsf{10}$}, ylabel={Ordinate, $y$}]`